# Limiting digits in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am using ArcMap 10.2.

I want to create a land information system, one of the features attribute data includes a citizen id field, it includes 11 digits, for preventing wrong value entering, i want to limit the digit number, so the operators can not enter more than 11 digit in the field of attribute table.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using a text/string  field.  You can limit the length to 11 characters.

Alternatively, if you're using ArcGIS, you can set up a range domain.  The minimum value would be 10000000000 and the maximum would be 99999999999.

[image]

Comment: see my edit which explains how to do it with a Double field in a geodatabase.

Comment: A lot of thanks to you Fezter, now i'm trying to do it

Comment: Just thinking out aloud, what if they want to store the "digit" 00000000010, using a range domain won't work as it will drop off all the leading zeros. If @user34941 wants to store leading zeros then they would have to store it as a 11 character string.

Answer (score 0):

most practical and logical soluiton is creating field as text, citizen id will not be used for any arithmetical process, i tried the solution above but program rounds the number and it can create problem